# Iriun Webcam Does not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam

Iriun webcam was working great in elementary os based on ubuntu 18.04 (with setting if_names=0 in grub) but I had to switch to ubuntu 20.04. In ubuntu 20.04 as soon as I lauch the client it shows a message "initialization failed, you may want to run: sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1" (off course with if_names=0). Running this command has no effect. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

A kernel upgrade solved the problem.